# Tempdata,Session value become null when redirect to other action methods?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to persist value through all action method I have read other post where they use session but this could not solve my problem too,any other solution. thanks.

> view

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("ViewPendingReocrd", "Dashboard")" class="fa fa-search">
           <span>Pending Records</span>
 <span class="pull-right-container">

       <span class="label label-primary pull-right">  
              @TempData["Pending"]
       </span>                       
 </span>

  </a>
```

> Controller

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(*) as count from ClaimOrder where ClaimStatus='P'", conn)) 
                {
                    TempData["Pending"]= (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    TempData.Keep();

                }
```

Comment: juts out of curiosity, why cant session solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**ViewData and ViewBag** -> Transfer data from controller to view.

**TempData** -> Keeps data for the time of HTTP Request, which means that it holds data between two consecutive requests.

**Session** -> Session is valid for all requests, not for a single redirect.

If you want to persist value through all action, use session.

More info >> https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/viewdata-vs-viewbag-vs-tempdata-vs-session